# Warning: cast from pointer from/to integer of different size on RIOT OS

Tags: gcc, msp430, riot-os

I tried to compile this program with gcc 4.8.4, then this program will be uploaded to the board MSP430. 
And I get the warning

```
/home/doni/RIOT-tcp/examples/gnrc_tcp_srv/main.c:117:19: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
```

This error comes for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "thread.h"
#include "net/af.h"
#include "net/gnrc/ipv6.h"
#include "net/conn/tcp.h"

#define ENABLE_DEBUG (0)
#include "debug.h"

#ifndef LOCAL_PORT
#define LOCAL_PORT 80         /* The Portnumber the server is listening on */
#endif

#ifndef BACKLOG
#define BACKLOG 2             /* Number of possible parallel connections */
#endif

#ifndef NBYTE
#define NBYTE (2048)          /* Amount of data to transmit */
#endif

conn_tcp_t conn;
conn_tcp_t conn_queue[BACKLOG];

uint8_t bufs[BACKLOG][NBYTE];
uint8_t stacks[BACKLOG][THREAD_STACKSIZE_DEFAULT + THREAD_EXTRA_STACKSIZE_PRINTF];

void *srv_thread(__attribute__((unused)) void *arg);

int main(void)
{
    kernel_pid_t ifs[GNRC_NETIF_NUMOF];
    ipv6_addr_t local_addr;
    gnrc_ipv6_netif_t *entry = NULL;
    char ipv6_addr_str[IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN];
    int32_t err = 0;

    /* Disable 15.4 Retransmissions on the first network device */
    //netopt_enable_t opt = NETOPT_ENABLE;
    netopt_enable_t opt = NETOPT_DISABLE;
    gnrc_netif_get(ifs);
    gnrc_netapi_set(ifs[0], NETOPT_AUTOACK, 0, &opt, sizeof(opt));
    gnrc_netapi_set(ifs[0], NETOPT_ACK_REQ, 0, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    printf("\nStarting server: LOCAL_PORT=%d, BACKLOG=%d, NBYTE=%d\n\n", LOCAL_PORT, BACKLOG, NBYTE);

    /* Print all link-local addresses of the server */
    printf("The Server listens on the following addresses: \n");
    entry = gnrc_ipv6_netif_get(ifs[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < GNRC_IPV6_NETIF_ADDR_NUMOF; i++) {
        if ((ipv6_addr_is_link_local(&entry->addrs[i].addr)) && !(entry->addrs[i].flags & GNRC_IPV6_NETIF_ADDR_FLAGS_NON_UNICAST)) {
            ipv6_addr_to_str(ipv6_addr_str, &entry->addrs[i].addr, IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN);
            printf("  - %s\n", ipv6_addr_str);
        }
    }

    /* Connection should accept from all address connections) */
    ipv6_addr_set_unspecified(&local_addr);

    /* Create connection struct */
    err = conn_tcp_create(&conn, &local_addr, sizeof(ipv6_addr_t), AF_INET6, LOCAL_PORT);
    switch (err) {
        case 0:
            DEBUG("conn_tcp_create() : 0 : ok \n");
            break;

        case -EINVAL:
            printf("conn_tcp_create() : -EINVAL : Invalid addr_len \n");
            break;

        case -EADDRNOTAVAIL:
            printf("conn_tcp_create() : -EADDRNOTAVAIL : Invalid addr \n");
            break;

        case -EAFNOSUPPORT:
            printf("conn_tcp_create() : -EAFNOSUPPORT : Invalid AF-Family\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("conn_tcp_create() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected return value: Go fix it!\n", err);
    }

    /* Initialize connection structs to wait for incomming connections */
    err = conn_tcp_listen(&conn, conn_queue, sizeof(conn_queue) / sizeof(conn_queue[0]));
    switch (err) {
        case -EADDRINUSE:
            printf("conn_tcp_listen() : -EADDRINUSE : Address is already in use\n");
            return 0;

        case -EAFNOSUPPORT:
            printf("conn_tcp_listen() : -EAFNOSUPPORT: conn and conn_queue have a different address format\n");
            return 0;

        default:
            DEBUG("conn_tcp_listen() : %"PRIi32" : ok, %"PRIi32" connections are waiting for peers\n", err, err);
    }

    /* Start Threads to handle each connection */
    for (int i = 0; i < err; i += 1) {
        thread_create((char *)stacks[i], sizeof(stacks[i]), THREAD_PRIORITY_MAIN, 0, srv_thread, (void *)(intptr_t)i, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *srv_thread(__attribute__((unused)) void *arg)
{
    int32_t tid = (int32_t)arg;
    int32_t err = 0;
    uint32_t rcvd = 0;
    uint32_t sent = 0;
    uint32_t cycles = 0;

    /* Structs to hold connection Info */
    ipv6_addr_t local_addr;
    ipv6_addr_t peer_addr;
    char local_addr_str[IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN];
    char peer_addr_str[IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN];
    uint16_t local_port;
    uint16_t peer_port;

    /* Handle on the current Connection */
    conn_tcp_t *peer = NULL;

    /* Connection handling code */
    DEBUG("Srv running: TID=%"PRIi32"\n", tid);
    while (1) {
        /* Handle incomming Connection */
        err = conn_tcp_accept(&conn, &peer);
        switch (err) {
            case 0:
                DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_accept() : 0 : ok \n", tid);
                break;

            case -EOPNOTSUPP:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_accept() : -EOPNOTSUPP : Operation not supported on active Connection\n", tid);
                return 0;

            case -EAGAIN:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_accept() : -EAGAIN : All pending connections are already handled\n", tid);
                return 0;

            default:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_accept() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected return value: Go fix it!\n", tid, err);
                return 0;
        }

        /* Get Connections local Info */
        err = conn_tcp_getlocaladdr(peer, &local_addr, &local_port);
        switch (err) {
            case 0:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getlocaladdr() : 0 : No Address copied\n", tid);
                break;

            default:
                if (!ipv6_addr_equal((ipv6_addr_t *)peer->local_addr, &local_addr)) {
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getlocaladdr() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected local Address\n", tid, err);
                    break;
                }
                if (peer->local_port != local_port) {
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getlocaladdr() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected local Port\n", tid, err);
                    break;
                }
                DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getlocaladdr() : %"PRIi32" : ok\n", tid, err);
                break;
        }

        /* Get Connections peer Info */
        err = conn_tcp_getpeeraddr(peer, &peer_addr, &peer_port);
        switch (err) {
            case 0:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getpeeraddr() : 0 : No Address copied\n", tid);
                break;

            default:
                if (!ipv6_addr_equal((ipv6_addr_t *)peer->peer_addr, &peer_addr)) {
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getpeeraddr() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected peer Address\n", tid, err);
                    break;
                }
                if (peer->peer_port != peer_port) {
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getpeeraddr() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected peer Port\n", tid, err);
                    break;
                }
                DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_getpeeraddr() : %"PRIi32" : ok\n", tid, err);
                break;
        }

        /* Print Connection info */
        ipv6_addr_to_str(local_addr_str, &local_addr, IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN);
        ipv6_addr_to_str(peer_addr_str, &peer_addr, IPV6_ADDR_MAX_STR_LEN);
        DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : Connection Info : Local=[%s]:%"PRIu16" -- Peer=[%s]:%"PRIu16"\n", tid, local_addr_str, local_port, peer_addr_str, peer_port);

        /* Receive Data */
        for (rcvd = 0; rcvd < sizeof(bufs[tid]); rcvd += err) {
            err = conn_tcp_recv(peer, (void *)(bufs[tid] + rcvd), sizeof(bufs[tid]) - rcvd);
            switch (err) {
                case -EPERM:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_rcvd() : -EPERM : No permission. Caller is not the owner of the connection\n", tid);
                    return 0;

                case -EALREADY:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_rcvd() : -EALREADY : Connection already closed or closing\n", tid);
                    continue;

                case -ETIME:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_rcvd() : -ETIME : User call Timeout. Reconnect\n", tid);
                    continue;

                default:
                    if (err >= 0) {
                        DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_rcvd() : %"PRIi32" : %"PRIi32" Bytes received from Peer=[%s]:%"PRIu16"\n", tid, err, err, peer_addr_str, peer_port);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_rcvd() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected return value: Go fix it!\n", tid, err);
                        return 0;
                    }
            }
        }

        /* Check received data against test pattern */
        for (uint32_t i=0; i < sizeof(bufs[tid]) - 1; i+= 2){
            if( bufs[tid][i] != 0xFF || bufs[tid][i+1] != 0x00 ) {
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : Payload verfication failed\n", tid);
                break;
            }
        }

        /* Fill Buffer with a test pattern */
        for (uint32_t i=0; i < sizeof(bufs[tid]) - 1; i+= 2){
            bufs[tid][i] = 0xAA;
            bufs[tid][i+1] = 0x77;
        }

        /* Send Data */
        for (sent = 0; sent < sizeof(bufs[tid]); sent += err) {
            err = conn_tcp_send(peer, bufs[tid] + sent, sizeof(bufs[tid]) - sent);
            switch (err) {
                case -EPERM:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_send() : -EPERM : No permission. Caller is not the owner of the connection\n", tid);
                    return 0;

                case -EALREADY:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_send() : -EALREADY : Connection already closed or closing\n", tid);
                    continue;

                case -ETIME:
                    printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_send() : -ETIME : User call Timeout. Reconnect\n", tid);
                    continue;

                default:
                    if (err >= 0) {
                        DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_send() : %"PRIi32" : %"PRIi32" Bytes sent to Peer=[%s]:%"PRIu16"\n", tid, err, err, peer_addr_str, peer_port);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_send() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected return value: Go fix it!\n", tid, err);
                        return 0;
                    }
            }
        }

        /* Close Connection */
        err = conn_tcp_close(peer);
        switch (err) {
            case 0:
                DEBUG("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_close() : 0 : ok\n", tid);
                break;

            case -EPERM:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_close() : -EPERM : No permission. Caller is not the owner of the connection\n", tid);
                break;

            case -EALREADY:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_close() : -EALREADY : Connection already closed or closing\n", tid);
                continue;

            case -ETIME:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_close() : -ETIME : User call Timeout. Reconnect\n", tid);
                continue;

            default:
                printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : conn_tcp_close() : %"PRIi32" : Unexpected return value: Go fix it!\n", tid, err);
        }

        printf("TID=%"PRIi32" : %"PRIi32" test cycles completed\n", tid, cycles);
        cycles += 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

problems in the

```
int32_t tid = (int32_t)arg;
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 1):

This code was written for a 32-bit CPU.
But on the MSP430, a pointer has 16 bits, so it would not be possible to stuff a 32-bit number into it.

Some of the code alreay used `intptr_t` to get a numeric type that fits into a pointer, but other places use `int32_t`.

You have to replace those occurrences of `int32_t` where pointer values are handled. But, more importantly, you also have to check that these numbers actually fit into a 16-bit type.